# How to increase zxing captureactivity scanning speed

Tags: android, zxing, scanning

I am using Zxing library for scanning barcodes in my Android project. Scanning speed is very slow when I connect my bluetooth scanner and scan any barcode. Is there any way I can increase scanning speed?